# How do I replace all NaNs in a pandas dataframe with the string "None"

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe and some of them are empty. I want to make it a None string so I can parse it easier than a NaN value.

Comment: None a python object, NaN is a float type which is better suited to represent missing data. Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.replace(np.nan, 'None', regex=True)
```

Use the code above.

Comment: `regex=True` this is not going to work especially since you are not replacing strings (np.nan is not a string)